# Guidelines on how and when to keep cordova app running in background

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova aka Phonegap app, that receives emails from server using BOSH technology. User will me getting IM messages and also emails from other users. For this I need to run my app in background forever until and unless user forcefully want to close it. I have gone through different plugins like https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.

And also options like `<preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />`

And gone through [articles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) at Apple developer site.

And some plugin says location permission need to be granted for iOS app to run JS in background.

After going through all the above, I have got few questions as I am not native developer and mostly depend on my JS skills and Cordova plugins (I heart fully thank their authors).

My Target platforms are iOS, Android, WP7, WP8, Blackberry

Below are my questions

1. What is the best way to keep JS running in the background so that user will receive mails and messages uninterruptedly as they are very important for user.
2. Are there any plugins available and which are accepted by appStore team people.
3. Does push notifications help in this case? If yes my server does not have any other integrations to let other servers know what is new message, how can I overcome this.
4. Does appStore reject these kind of apps running in the background?

Please help me, I am in need of answers for these questions, not just asking for learning purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: If you've got 4 questions, I suggest asking them in 4 different posts. Also, please show your previous code for each question individually. So, if you post question 1 for example, show what you've tried to make this work, or what you've found on Google so far.

Comment: @Joeytje50 You have asked absolutely correct points, but I have already mentioned in my question that I have gone through them but did not understand properly as I am not native JAVA or Objective C developer. And I have mentioned code and also plugin too in code. I am just asking guidelines. Thanks

Comment: Then I recommend you first get to know the language. Stackoverflow is a place for more specific questions about programming. Your questions are just a bit too broad for this site. If you can ask more specific questions, there's a much greater chance somebody will be able to answer it specifically, giving you just what you need.

Comment: @Joeytje50 - too much regulations here, this is a very good question about a very well known issue and experts could have offered some good solution. SO is gradually turning into some kind of European Union...